# How do I fix my shell script for this curl command

Tags: json, shell, curl

Hey guys I'm running a shell script through a few loops to acquire records but the curl command is giving me an invalid json error, what am I doing wrong?

```
resp=$(curl -g -u "${usr}":"${pwd}" -X GET "${env}"/"${name}"/res/"${type}"?where={%22timestamp%22:{%22$gt%22:{%22$date%22:%22"${date1}"%22},%22$lt%22:{%22$date%22:%22"${date2}"%22}}}&paging=limit:100,page:${i})
```

Comment: Have you using something above that line to find out what command line you're sending to curl? Something like
`echo "${env}"/"${name}"/res/"${type}"?where={%22timestamp%22:{%22$gt%22:{%22$date%22:%22"${date1}"%22},%22$lt%22:{%22$date%22:%22"${date2}"%22}}}&paging=limit:100,page:${i}`

Comment: ...and note that you would want to escape that `&` before bash thinks you want to fork

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting hell. printf can help:

```
url=$(printf '%s/%s/res/%s?where={%%22timestamp%%22:{%%22$gt%%22:{%%22$date%%22:%%22%s%%22},%%22$lt%%22:{%%22$date%%22:%%22%s%%22}}}&paging=limit:100,page:%s' "$env" "$name" "$type" "$date1" "$date2" "$i")

resp=$(curl -g -u "$usr:$pwd" -X GET "$url")
```

Comment: Note that the % in `%22` needs to be doubled so printf sees a literal %: `%%22`